# Pandas read_csv parse_dates from 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have not found a post here that quite fits my situation.  I have a csv file where the first column is year (2002), the second column is Month (January) and the third column is MonthCode (1 for January, etc).  I would like to import into a Pandas dataframe to create a full date index.  The following code gives an error, but should show you what I am trying to do.

The error is:
ValueError: time data '2002' does not match format '%Y%b%d'

Note: I do not have a Day of the month in the data so I have to use the first or last, unless there is a way to index on just Year and Month with no Day.

The data looks like this:

```
Year    Month   Month Code  District Code   District
2002    January 1   1   Albany
2002    January 1   2   Allegany
2002    January 1   3   Broome
2002    January 1   4   Cattaraugus
2002    January 1   5   Cayuga
```

The code that does not work:

```
file = 'C:/.../snap.csv'

parser = lambda date: pd.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%b%d')


# create dataframe from csv file
snapdf = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates = [0,1], date_parser = parser)
# NOTE: I also tried parse_dates = [0,2] but same error
```

Answer (score 0):

I altered the data to make it more obvious how the dates gets parsed into the dataframe

```
Year,Month,Month Code,District Code,District
2002,January,1,1,Albany
2004,February,1,2,Allegany
2005,December,1,3,Broome
2007,August,1,4,Cattaraugus
2001,March,1,5,Cayuga
```

using `parse_dates` parameter with column 1-3:

```
>>>> with open('snap.csv') as f:
       df = pd.read_csv(f, parse_dates={'Date': [0,1,2]}, index_col='Date')

>>>> df
            District Code     District
Date                                  
2002-01-01              1       Albany
2004-02-01              2     Allegany
2005-12-01              3       Broome
2007-08-01              4  Cattaraugus
2001-03-01              5       Cayuga

>>>> df.District
Date
2002-01-01         Albany
2004-02-01       Allegany
2005-12-01         Broome
2007-08-01    Cattaraugus
2001-03-01         Cayuga
Name: District, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you but it does not work.  Column 2 is irrelevant if you use column 1 - iow, January in column 1 as month number 1 in column 2.  And when you get to February, it looks the same as January:70 2002-01-01  February           2             13      Dutchess   
71 2002-01-01  February           2             14          Erie   
72 2002-01-01  February           2             15         Essex   
73 2002-01-01  February           2             16      Franklin

Comment: what's your expected result? my example used `Month code` column in csv as date replacement so all dates are 1st of the month. your comment includes default numbered index, which indicates you didn't include `index_col='Date'` flag i put in my code (which should result in a `DatetimeIndex` dataframe -> `DatetimeIndex(['2002-01-01', '2004-02-01', '2005-12-01', '2007-08-01', '2001-03-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)`)

Comment: It works, except for one issue.  The month code is the number of the month, so in Feb it is 02, in March it is 03, etc.  So you cannot use it as the Day.  Doing so causes the following in Feb - 2002-02-02 14 Erie    36161   
2002-02-02             15         Essex                   1151
2002-02-02             16      Franklin                   1647   
 NOTE that in Feb all dates are the second.  In March all dates are the third, etc.  I need to basically hard code the Day 01 into the read_csv code if that can be done.  Or do it after the fact.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this running and it was actually quite simple in the end.

```
snapdf["DateIndex"] = pd.to_datetime(snapdf['Year'].astype(str), format='%Y')
```

This takes the value from the Year column of a dataframe (stored as Int) and converts it to a datestring in a new column DateIndex.  Because there are no month or day data, it automatically inserts 01/01 as the month and day.

So, 2017 in the Year column becomes 01/10/2017